# "Base table or view not found" in Data Migration Tool PostProcessing Step - Prefix Missing

Tags: magento2.3, magento2-migration-tool, magento-2-commerce

I am migrating a Magento EE 1.14.4.2 to Magento Commerce 2.3.2 using the [Data Migration Tool 2.3.2](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/tree/2.3.2).  It appears to be processing correctly until it fails about 50 minutes later on the PostProcessing step with the following error...

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'magento2.catalog_product_entity_int' doesn't exist, query was: DELETE
>   FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` WHERE (value_id IN
>   ('535690','545428','546868','551863','551890','551899','551908','551926',
>   ...

The source database has no table prefix and the destination database has a table prefix which are both declared as such in the config.xml *(user, password and crypt keys have been removed and db names and prefix tweaked here for security)*...

**vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/commerce-to-commerce/1.14.4.2/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
    <steps mode="settings">
        <step title="Settings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
        </step>
        <step title="Stores Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="data">
        <step title="Data Integrity Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
        </step>
        <step title="EAV Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Custom Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\CustomCustomerAttributes\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\CustomCustomerAttributes\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\CustomCustomerAttributes\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version11410to2000</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version11410to2000</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version11410to2000</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Ratings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesOrder Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesOrder\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\SalesOrder\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesOrder\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGridsEE\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\OrderGridsEE\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGridsEE\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Tier Price Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Inventory Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Inventory\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Inventory\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Inventory\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="VisualMerchandiser Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\VisualMerchandiser\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\VisualMerchandiser\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\VisualMerchandiser\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="PostProcessing Step">
            <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="delta">
        <step title="Custom Customer Attributes Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\CustomCustomerAttributes\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\CustomCustomerAttributes\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Log\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesOrder Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\SalesOrder\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesOrder\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\OrderGridsEE\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGridsEE\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Inventory Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Inventory\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Inventory\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <source>
        <database host="localhost" name="magento1" user="my_user" password="my_password" />
    </source>
    <destination>
        <database host="localhost" name="magento2" user="my_user" password="my_password" />
    </destination>
    <options>
        <map_file>etc/commerce-to-commerce/1.14.4.2/map.xml</map_file>
        <eav_map_file>etc/commerce-to-commerce/map-eav.xml.dist</eav_map_file>
        <eav_document_groups_file>etc/commerce-to-commerce/eav-document-groups.xml.dist</eav_document_groups_file>
        <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/commerce-to-commerce/eav-attribute-groups.xml</eav_attribute_groups_file>
        <log_map_file>etc/commerce-to-commerce/map-log.xml.dist</log_map_file>
        <log_document_groups_file>etc/commerce-to-commerce/log-document-groups.xml.dist</log_document_groups_file>
        <settings_map_file>etc/commerce-to-commerce/settings.xml.dist</settings_map_file>
        <customer_map_file>etc/commerce-to-commerce/map-customer.xml.dist</customer_map_file>
        <customer_document_groups_file>etc/commerce-to-commerce/customer-document-groups.xml.dist</customer_document_groups_file>
        <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/commerce-to-commerce/customer-attribute-groups.xml.dist</customer_attribute_groups_file>
        <sales_order_map_file>etc/commerce-to-commerce/map-sales.xml.dist</sales_order_map_file>
        <delta_document_groups_file>etc/commerce-to-commerce/deltalog.xml.dist</delta_document_groups_file>
        <customer_attr_map_file>etc/commerce-to-commerce/customer-attr-map.xml.dist</customer_attr_map_file>
        <customer_attr_document_groups_file>etc/commerce-to-commerce/customer-attr-document-groups.xml.dist</customer_attr_document_groups_file>
        <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/commerce-to-commerce/order-grids-document-groups.xml.dist</order_grids_document_groups_file>
        <class_map>etc/commerce-to-commerce/class-map.xml.dist</class_map>
        <visual_merchandiser_map>etc/commerce-to-commerce/visual_merchandiser_map.xml.dist</visual_merchandiser_map>
        <visual_merchandiser_document_groups>etc/commerce-to-commerce/visual_merchandiser_document_groups.xml.dist</visual_merchandiser_document_groups>
        <visual_merchandiser_attribute_groups>etc/commerce-to-commerce/visual_merchandiser_attribute_groups.xml.dist</visual_merchandiser_attribute_groups>
        <map_document_groups>etc/commerce-to-commerce/map-document-groups.xml.dist</map_document_groups>
        <tier_price_map_file>etc/commerce-to-commerce/1.14.4.2/map-tier-price.xml.dist</tier_price_map_file>
        <stores_map_file>etc/commerce-to-commerce/map-stores.xml.dist</stores_map_file>
        <!--
        In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
        -->
        <bulk_size>100</bulk_size>
        <!--
        Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
        NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
        and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
         -->
        <direct_document_copy>1</direct_document_copy>
        <source_prefix />
        <dest_prefix>abc123_</dest_prefix>
        <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>1</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
        <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
        <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
        <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
        <edition_migrate>commerce-to-commerce</edition_migrate>
        <edition_number>1.14.4.2</edition_number>
        <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
        <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
        <crypt_key>REMOVED</crypt_key>
    </options>
</config>
```

It appears that the data migration tool is trying to delete records from that table without using the proper prefix for the destination site.  Am I missing a setting here or is this some kind of bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this appears to be a bug within the tool.  I tested just hardcoding my table prefix in the tool under **src/Migration/step/PostProcessing/Data/AttributeSetLeftoverDataCleaner.php** and it completed successfully...

```
$this->destination->deleteRecords('magento2_' . $document, 'value_id', $entityValueIds[$document]);
```

As a result, I opened an issue with Magento on this... https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/708

Comment: hi @Scruffy, so the data migration went success correct? no issue with this error?

Comment: Yes, this was fixed as of the 2.3.3 migration tool... https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/pull/725